# PyPNG read 48-bit, change pixel color, write pixel back

Tags: python, png, pixel, pypng

I was wondering if someone could post an example using PyPNG to read a 48-bit image (16 bit channel R,G, and B), get and display a specific pixel color (say pixel 88 or whatever), change that value, and write it back into the png.
I found the documentation to be very sparse, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def readPNG2(f):
    r=png.Reader(f)
    r.read()
    print r.bitdepth
```

this produces a result of 16. I saved my image out of Photoshop as 16 per channel (48-bit). What am I missing, is this in fact saying 16 bits per channel?

Comment: I am stuck on syntax it looks like:
def readPNG2(FileName):
   r=png.Reader(filenameherehow?)
    r.read()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that would mean 16 bits per channel. 16 or 15 bits per pixel is mostly a thing of the past. The docu explains how to [load 16bpc into a numpy array](http://packages.python.org/pypng/ex.html#png-to-numpy-array-reading).

The API of PyPNG seems to be very low-level, only one step away from directly using libpng from C. (See the [libpng manual](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-manual.txt) for more on that. It is an option to do that for a python application, e.g. MyPaint [does it via swig extension](https://gitorious.org/mypaint/mypaint/blobs/master/lib/fastpng.hpp).)